# I Can't Bring Data From Database to DropDownList Selectively (City and Town Things, System.NullReferenceException Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I'm facing a minor problem and I'll tell you all the details below. If you help me I would be very happy.

I have 3 tables in my database as "tbl_User", "tbl_City", "tbl_Town".

My "tbl_User" table:

- userid int [PK],
- email nvarchar(50),
- password nvarchar(50),
- city int,
- town int

My "tbl_City" table:

- cityno int [PK],
- cityname nvarchar(50)

My "tbl_Town" table:

- townno int,
- townname nvarchar(50),
- cityno int

As you can see, "tbl_City" and "tbl_Town" tables are related to each other. This means there are towns connected to every city.

1. While the user is registering on the site, he must choose city and town. So I can save city and town as number in "tbl_User".
2. **What I want to do is:** When the user goes "profile.aspx", I want the city and town name to be seen in DropDownLists selectively. And when user click DropDownListCity; I want all the other cities to appear at the same time. And when user click DropDownListTown; I want showing all towns connected to the selected city.
3. My code bring the city selected in the "tbl_User" and when I click DropDownListCity I can see all other cities. There is no problem here. But my code doesn't bring the town selectively. I get en error: 'System.NullReferenceException'. I think it's because the city is chosen in DropDownList but program does not see the city selected.

My code is as follows:

```
Fonksiyon function = new Fonksiyon();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetCity();
        GetTown();
        GetCityAndTownSelectively();
    }
}

private void GetCityAndTownSelectively()
{
    if (Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT tbl_City.cityno, tbl_City.cityname, tbl_Town.townno, tbl_Town.townname FROM tbl_User LEFT JOIN tbl_City on tbl_City.cityno = tbl_User.city LEFT JOIN tbl_Town on tbl_Town.townno = tbl_User.town WHERE userid=" + Session["userid"].ToString());
        if (dr == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownListCity.ClearSelection();
            DropDownListCity.Items.FindByValue(dr[0].ToString()).Selected = true;
            DropDownListTown.ClearSelection();
            DropDownListTown.Items.FindByValue(dr[2].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}

private void GetCity()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_City", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownListCity.DataSource = reader;
        DropDownListCity.DataValueField = "cityno";
        DropDownListCity.DataTextField = "cityname";
        DropDownListCity.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(message);
    }
}

private void GetTown()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Town WHERE cityno='" + DropDownListCity.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownListTown.DataSource = reader;
        DropDownListTown.DataValueField = "townno";
        DropDownListTown.DataTextField = "townname";
        DropDownListTown.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(mesaj);
    }
}

protected void DropDownListCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetTown();
}
```

Program gives the error in the following line: `DrpDwnLstTown.Items.FindByValue(dr[2].ToString()).Selected = true;` And I think i guess i found the cause of the error: When I changed my GetTown methods SQL query like this: `SELECT * FROM tbl_Town` my code brings town selectively but when I click DropDownListTown I see all towns. The problem is I have to only see the town connected to the city.

Comment: I wrote above but it's DrpDwnLstTown.Items.FindByValue(dr[2].ToString()).Selected = true; line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full code you need.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetCity();

            if (DropDownListCity.Items != null)
            {                    
                GetTown(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListCity.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetCity()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_City order by cityName", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownListCity.DataSource = reader;
            DropDownListCity.DataValueField = "cityno";
            DropDownListCity.DataTextField = "cityname";
            DropDownListCity.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
            Response.Write(message);
        }



    }



    private void GetTown(Int32  selectedCityNo)
    {
        if (selectedCityNo == 0)
        {
            DropDownListTown.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand comm;
            SqlDataReader reader;
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Town WHERE cityno='" + selectedCityNo.ToString() + "' order by townname", conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownListTown.DataSource = reader;
                DropDownListTown.DataValueField = "townno";
                DropDownListTown.DataTextField = "townname";
                DropDownListTown.DataBind();
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
                Response.Write(message);
            }


        }
    }

    protected void DropDownListCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlCity = (DropDownList)sender;
        string selectedID = ddlCity.ID;
        DropDownList ddlSelectedCity = (DropDownList)FindControl(selectedID);
        GetTown(Convert.ToInt32(ddlSelectedCity.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: I will tired you a little but how should I change GetTown() method? If you help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Please check the full code added now. You don't need GetCityAndTownSelectively(). If anything unclear, pls tell me

Comment: I am grateful for your time first. I've try your code and GetTown(int.Parse(DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.ToString())); this line I get an error like this: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: Please try to use        GetTown(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.ToString()));   instead of that line. full code added.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the same error, I don't know why. I want to ask a question: We do not use the user table in the codes, can we have the bring of the city and town information in the user table in this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154593/discussion-between-anura-adikari-and-shadouspan).